# How to capture app usage video like "SPB Wallet" did it?

Tags: android, video-capture

"SPB Wallet" have greate usage video (in terms of quality) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6y3sIqaSpo
How that was possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess they used the device emulator and captured the video with a screen grabber and saved the uncompressed stream. Then later on they cropped the video an put it inside the device image you see in the youtube video.

Comment: The have to smooth video for method based on debugger screen grabber, I think.